# Wordpress Custom Sidebar, Widgets Appearing Outside Aside Tag

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a custom sidebar in wordpress, and this was the working code in sidebar.php:

```
if ( ! is_active_sidebar( 'sidebar-1' ) ) {
    return;
}
?>

<aside id="secondary" class="sidebar-area widget-area">
    <div class="sidebar-area-wrap">
        <?php dynamic_sidebar( 'sidebar-1' ); ?>
    </div>
</aside><!-- #secondary -->
```

I added options to it in the functions.php(works), so now the code looks like this:

```
if ( ! is_active_sidebar( 'sidebar-1' ) ) {
    return;
}

$swag_sidebar_location = get_theme_mod('swag_sidebar_location');
if (isset($swag_sidebar_location) && $swag_sidebar_location=='') {
$swag_sidebar_location ='sidebar-location-none';
}

?>

<?php

if (isset($swag_sidebar_location) && $swag_sidebar_location=='sidebar-location-right' || $swag_sidebar_location=='sidebar-location-left') {
    echo '
        <aside id="secondary" class="sidebar-area widget-area">
            <div class="sidebar-area-wrap">
                ' . dynamic_sidebar( "sidebar-1" ) . '
            </div>
        </aside>
    ';
}

?>
```

The problem is the widgets are appearing outside and before the  tags, with the number "1" appearing appearing inside the  tag.

I'm guessing the problem lies here: `' . dynamic_sidebar( "sidebar-1" ) . '`
I don't know php, just trying to figure it out. How can I fix this?

EDIT: an example of what the HTML looks like this:

```
<section id="pages-2" class="widget">xxxxxx</section>
<section id="pages-2" class="widget">xxxxxx</section>
<section id="pages-2" class="widget">xxxxxx</section>
<section id="pages-2" class="widget">xxxxxx</section>
<aside id="secondary" class="sidebar-area widget-area sidebar-location-right">          <div class="sidebar-area-wrap">             1           </div>      </aside>
```

Instead of correctly looking like this:

```
<aside id="secondary" class="sidebar-area widget-area sidebar-location-right">           
    <div class="sidebar-area-wrap">
        <section id="pages-2" class="widget">xxxxxx</section>
        <section id="pages-2" class="widget">xxxxxx</section>
        <section id="pages-2" class="widget">xxxxxx</section>
        <section id="pages-2" class="widget">xxxxxx</section>
    </div>
</aside>
```

EDIT: as requested, my register sidebar code in functions.php

```
function swagger_widgets_init()
{
    register_sidebar(array(
        'name' => esc_html__('Sidebar', 'swagger'),
        'id' => 'sidebar-1',
        'description' => esc_html__('Add widgets here.', 'swagger'),
        'before_widget' => '<section id="%1$s" class="widget %2$s">',
        'after_widget' => '</section>',
        'before_title' => '<h2 class="widget-title"><span class="widget-title-span">',
        'after_title' => '</span></h2>'
    ));
}
add_action('widgets_init', 'swagger_widgets_init');
```

Comment: post your register sidebar code

Comment: @Vel added my register sidebar code,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Good old Wordpress and its *"functions that echo"*.

`dynamic_sidebar()` does not `return` a value; it `echo`'s one. This makes it unsuitable for concatenation in a string because its result will be `echo`'d during string evaluation, sending it to the output buffer before your string is even created.

Unfortunately, Wordpress does not provide a `get_*` version of this function to *return* the string (yet, see https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/13169).

Instead of concatenation, execute three separate calls. For example...

```php
echo '<aside id="secondary" class="sidebar-area widget-area"><div class="sidebar-area-wrap">';
dynamic_sidebar( "sidebar-1" );
echo '</div></aside>';
```

---

You could also use a single `echo` statement but instead of concatenating, pass it several comma-separated arguments, eg

```php
echo '<aside id="secondary" class="sidebar-area widget-area"><div class="sidebar-area-wrap">',
        dynamic_sidebar( "sidebar-1" ),
        '</div></aside>';
```

---

Another option is to stick with the original mixed HTML and PHP, wrapped in your `if` condition. Eg

```php
if (isset($swag_sidebar_location) && $swag_sidebar_location=='sidebar-location-right' || $swag_sidebar_location=='sidebar-location-left') : ?>
<aside id="secondary" class="sidebar-area widget-area">
    <div class="sidebar-area-wrap">
        <?php dynamic_sidebar( 'sidebar-1' ) ?>
    </div>
</aside>
<?php endif ?>
```

See http://php.net/manual/control-structures.alternative-syntax.php